# Exported Jar (Eclipse) Crashing on Startup

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export

I've made this program with Eclipse. When I launch it *from* Eclipse, it works flawlessly, but when I export to a runnable jar and launch that, it whitescreens. I tried running it through command prompt to see if I could get a decent error message. Turns out apparently it had something to do with image loading, specifically the case of the image title (still strange that it worked in Eclipse but not standalone). Anyway, fixed those issues, now I have a similar one - still something to do with image loading if I'm correct.

Here's my error output: http://pastebin.com/vPP0gWns

Can anyone offer any insight? Let me know if you need more info, any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks guys.

Edit: i think it's worth mentioning that while whitescreened, the application still loops the menu music until you close it.

Comment: Well the error message says: OutOfMemory... Give your app more memory when you start it... `java -Xms512m -Xmx512m -jar yourexecutable.jar`

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your comment, this fixed the issue when opening through command prompt, but is there a way to include memory allocation in a .jar file?

Comment: nope - not in the jar file. If you don't want to start the app via command line, you can always create a script that you can use, or you can e.g use [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)